# Auto completion in QtCreator for C++ types

Tags: c++, qt, autocomplete, qml, qt-creator

I define some classes in C++ to be used in QML.  When coding, I would like that QtCreator automatically lists all the available properties and functions of the C++ objects.

The following example illustrates the problem:
In C++ I define an Office class (with address property and a sendEmail method).  I also define a Company class (with a headquarters property and a list of offices).  The code of both classes is added at the end.

In `main.cpp` I add the following lines with the intention to make the types known to QML/javascript.

```
Company theCompany;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("theCompany", &theCompany);
qmlRegisterType<Office>();
```

However, this doesn't seem to be sufficient: in the QML code below, I list which properties/methods are auto-completed and which aren't

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    property var company: theCompany         //auto-completion OK
    property var hq: theCompany.headquarters //auto-completion OK
    property var hqAddress: hq.address       //auto-completion NOT OK
    property var offices: theCompany.offices //auto-completion OK
    property var firstOffice: offices[0]
    property var firstAddress:  firstOffice.address  //auto-completion NOT OK
    function update() {
        hq.sendEMail()                       //auto-completion NOT OK
    }
}
```

Hence the question is: can I make the `Office` type known to QML and if so, how?  Will this also work for a `QList<Office*>`?

Thanks in advance,

Marc

==================================

office.h

```
#ifndef OFFICE_H
#define OFFICE_H

#include <QObject>

class Office : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString address MEMBER m_address NOTIFY addressChanged)
public:
    explicit Office(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    Q_INVOKABLE void sendEMail(QString message){};

signals:
    void addressChanged();

public slots:

private:
    QString m_address;
};

#endif // OFFICE_H
```

office.cpp

```
#include "office.h"

Office::Office(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}
```

company.h

```
#ifndef COMPANY_H
#define COMPANY_H

#include <QObject>

#include "office.h"

class Company : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(Office* headquarters MEMBER m_headquarters NOTIFY headquartersChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QList<Office *> offices MEMBER m_offices NOTIFY officesChanged)
public:
    explicit Company(QObject *parent = nullptr);

signals:
    void officesChanged();
    void headquartersChanged();

public slots:
private:
    QList<Office*> m_offices;
    Office* m_headquarters;
};

#endif // COMPANY_H
```

company.cpp

```
#include "company.h"

Company::Company(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

#include "company.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    Company theCompany;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("theCompany", &theCompany);
    qmlRegisterType<Office*>();
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Known to QML and known to QtCreator are two very different things. The IDE is not perfect. It may not recognise things that the compiler/runtime are perfectly fine with.

Comment: @JesperJuhl  Valid point! 
I would like them to be "Known to QtCreator" to support auto-completion (if possible of course)

Comment: Why would you expect that the QtCreator can deliver you autocomplete for `Office` if the type is `var`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see:

```
property var company: theCompany         //auto-completion OK
property var hq: theCompany.headquarters //auto-completion OK
property var hqAddress: hq.address       //auto-completion NOT OK
property var offices: theCompany.offices //auto-completion OK
property var firstOffice: offices[0]
property var firstAddress:  firstOffice.address  //auto-completion NOT OK
function update() {
    hq.sendEMail()                       //auto-completion NOT OK
}
```

There I never see a

```
property Office firstOffice
```

I see

```
property var firstOffice
```

The type `var` has no property `address`, so there is no code completion.
The property only exists at runtime.
At least for me, when `Office` is registered (with a name) and the type is `Office`, QtCreator will give me proper code completion.

Same goes for `hq` - not even as reader of that QML file I have any idea, what type it might be. Why should the QtCreator know this?

---

BTW: Similar to the QtCreator, also the JIT has no knowledge on the properties, so with a type `var` in the equation, there won't be any [optimized bindings](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-performance.html#bindings).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know I could use Office instead of var (I knew I could use int, bool, ...).  I currently register Office with `qmlRegisterType<Office>();` but that doesn't seem to be sufficient.  Can you indicate how I should register Office?

Comment: You need to take the [overload](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterType) with the import uri, the minor and major version and a QML name, e.g. `qmlRegisterType<Office>("CompanyTypes", 1, 0, "Office");` then you can import in the QML file: `import CompanyTypes 1.0` and you have the type available. This however only works, if the type is default constructible. Otherwise you can create a QML interface class, that you register like this, and inherit the real type from it.

Comment: Thanks!  Using `qmlRegisterUncreatableType<Office>("CompanyTypes", 1, 0, "Office", "error message");` also seems to work fine!

Comment: Ok, I always had some issues with all the other ways to register anything. I don't recall what they were, but some things I wanted to do were never working out, but if it works for you, it is great.